# Swift 4: Cannot use instance member 'MAIN_URL' within property initializer when trying to concatenate two strings

Tags: swift, variables

I am trying to concatenate a String variable with a text, but I keep getting this error:

```
import UIKit
public class GlobalClass {
  private let MAIN_URL = "http://example.com"
  private let GET_TOKEN_URL = URL(string: MAIN_URL + "loginUser") //here I get: Cannot use instance member 'MAIN_URL' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available
}
```

Is there any way to fix this? What I am trying to do is declaring those constants in a global swift file, so they will be accessible from other classes. I know they are private but I will be able to get their value by using getters.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need to make both properties `static` or make `GET_TOKEN_URL` lazy. This will make sure that the property initializer has access to `self` by the time the property is accessed for the first time.

`static` approach:

```
public class GlobalClass {
  private static let MAIN_URL = "http://example.com"
  private static let GET_TOKEN_URL = URL(string: GlobalClass.MAIN_URL + "loginUser")
}
```

`lazy` approach:

```
public class GlobalClass {
  private let MAIN_URL = "http://example.com"
  private lazy var GET_TOKEN_URL = URL(string: MAIN_URL + "loginUser")
}
```

You should also conform to the Swift naming convention, which is lowerCamelCase for variable names, so `mainUrl` and `getTokenUrl`.

Comment: Don't think being class here matter as properties are let ,and those are considered static constants that the app not gonna change in runtime

Comment: @Sh_Khan even in the case of immutable properties, the property initialisers get called before the class initializer would finish execution and hence properties cannot access other properties from inside their own property initialisers.

Comment: also despite lazy approach works Do you think spreading `GlobalClass()` is a good idea for static values

Comment: @Sh_Khan what do you mean by spreading? There are no `static` values using the `lazy` approach

Comment: I have tried both of your codes and they work perfectly! Thank you to you both for your help :)

Comment: I mean making a value type object is good approach than reference type ,  if op follows lazy approach then he has to create object like `GlobalClass()` or make a global var which isn't a good idea

Comment: @AdriánT95 you have to think the usage difference between a class and a struct

Comment: @Sh_Khan that's pretty much unrelated to the actual problem OP was facing, but yes, I'd suggest using a type with only static properties or using a singleton. Whether the `Globals` type is a reference or value type doesn't really make a difference in this case IMO.

Comment: @DávidPásztor i'm saying that the lazy approach is no the right way here , and the static i already mentioned it in my answer, i bet that the op will select the static approach

Answer (score 0):

I think you need

```
struct Globals {
    static let MAIN_URL = "http://example.com/"
    static let GET_TOKEN_URL = URL(string: Globals.MAIN_URL + "loginUser") //here I get: Cannot use instance member 'MAIN_URL' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available
}
```

`MAIN_URL` is not in a scope that let's you use it directly like `MAIN_URL` in your case you can do

```
private let GET_TOKEN_URL = URL(string: GlobalClass().MAIN_URL + "loginUser")
```